# How do you submit a form , make new text pop up and stay on the same page?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner in web development and I have a project where I have a form where you enter your name, surname and address and when you submit the form a text has to pop up under it. However, when I click the next button I have made after filling the form , the page just reloads instead of popping up a text and stay on the page .

My code :

```js
function gotostep3(){

//makes the new element I have made visible
document.getElementById("step3").style.visibility='visible';

}



function checkdata(){  //validates my input 

var a = document.getElementById("address");
var n = document.getElementById("address-num");
var r = document.getElementById("region");

  if(!(/\d/.test(a.value)) && !(/\d/.test(r.value))){
  
  }
  else{
    alert('no submit');  
    return false;
  }
    
   for (i = 0 ; i < n.value.length ; i++) {
      if ((n.value.charAt(i) < '0') || (n.value.charAt(i) > '9')){ 
   alert('Not integer');
   return false; 
   }
    }
 
 
   for (i = 0 ; i < p.value.length ; i++) {
      if ((p.value.charAt(i) < '0') || (p.value.charAt(i) > '9')){ 
   return false; 
    }
  }
 
  //if my input is all correct go to next step
 gotostep3();
 

return true;

}
```

```html
<div class = "form-area" id = "forma"> 
 
 <form  class = "sign-form" > 
  
  <div class = "form-container">
  
        <h1> Enter purchase data below : </h1>   
  
        <label for "dieythinsi" >  Address Name</label>
           <input type = "text" placeholder = "Enter address name " id = "address" name = "addr" required/> 
  </label>
   
  
  
        <label for "arithmos-dieyth" >  Address Number</label>
           <input type = "text" placeholder = "Enter address number " id = "address-num" name = "addnum" required/> 
        </label>

  
        <label for "perioxi" > Region </label>
  
          <input type = "text" placeholder = "Enter region "id = "region" name = "reg" required/> 
        </label>
  
  
   </div>
       <button class = "cancelbtn"  onclick = "goback()">Go back</button> 
       <button  class="continuebtn" onclick = "return  checkdata()">Next</button>
    
 
  
 </form>
 
 
 //the text I want to pop up after the form is filled 
    <h1 id = "step3"> Step 3 : Select way of payment to finish. </h1>  <br/>

 </div>
```

I would appreciate your help with guiding me to solve this task . Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify the button type
`<button  class="continuebtn" onclick = "return  checkdata()" type="button">Next</button>`

Comment: Yes you can say type = "onsumbit" but it justs changes my page . I don't want my page to change

Comment: there is no `type = "onsubmit"`. type define your input type. currently you use button so define it as a button

Comment: I just had to write button type = "button" . It solved my problem . Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

You were probably looking for an ajax form. Add this script (you need JQuery):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(".sign-form").submit(function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();

  var $form = $( this ),
      url = $form.attr( 'action' );
  var posting = $.post( url, { address: $('#address').val(), addressnum : $('#address-num').val(), region : $('#region').val() } );

  /* Alerts the results */
  posting.done(function( data ) {
    $form.replaceWith("<p>Form submitted!</p>");
  });
});
```

Comment: I have not learned Jquery yet . I am not allowed to use it either for this project

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I just had to specify my button type with button type = "button" instead of button type = "submit".Thank you for your time.